# Android setText with leading zero not showing the zero

Tags: java, android

An example of what I'm trying to do.

```
int i = 9;

if (i<10)
i = "0"+v1
```

Of course that won't work because int != String, but what would be the best way to do this, to make sure I have a leading zero appear? Convert the int to String?

Comment: Why not put another String to contain the value? String str = "0" + i;

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try [`String.format`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29)

```
int i = 9
String formattedValue = String.format("%02d", i);
```

Comment: Have used this a couple of times. Works awesome!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have an integer number with leading zero, as octol numbers are represented by a leading zero.you should convert you int to String using [**Integer.toString(int)**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toString%28int%29) method.

```
        int i = 9;
        System.out.println("0"+Integer.toString(i));
```

Or simply

```
      int i=0;
      String result ="0"+i;
```

Comment: I believe the Integer.toString(i) is not necessary in this case because appending to something that's not a string to something that is a string implicitly converts the non-string object to a string.

Comment: @gsingh2011 yepp, true.. that'd work as well :) i updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

some times when you set fonts for your projects it's better to use `DecimalFormat` class in java
this is another solution for this problem

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("00");
int number = 9;
String result = df.format(number) //09
```